# How to keep users from getting past login screen of App before logging in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

The first screen it goes to is the login screen but, I can just click any button on the Actionbar bypassing the login screen. I even thought of removing the Actionbar buttons then I could just put them back if login is successful but, I could not figure out how to call the id's of the Actionbar from the login screen class. What is the best way to keep a user from bypassing the login screen of the App?

Python code:

```
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import mainthread
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView


Builder.load_file('main.kv')


class Menu(BoxLayout):
    manager = ObjectProperty(None)


class ScreenLogIn(Screen):




    @mainthread
    def verify_credentials(self):


        try:



           if self.ids.login.text == "email@email.com" and self.ids.passw.text == "password":
            self.manager.current = "match"
        else:

            popup = Popup(title='Try again',
                          content=Label(text='Wrong Email/Password'),
                          size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400),
                          auto_dismiss=True)
            popup.open()
    except Exception as e:
        pass


class ScreenNearUsers(Screen):

    @mainthread
    def on_enter(self):

    for i in xrange(101):
        button = Button(text="B_" + str(i))
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(button)


class ScreenMatch(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenChats(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenUserProfile(Screen):
    pass


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    screen_log_in = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_near_user = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_match = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_chats = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_user_profile = ObjectProperty(None)


class MenuApp(App):

    def build(self):
       return Menu()


if __name__ == '__main__':
       MenuApp().run()
```

Main kv:

```
<Menu>:
    manager: screen_manager
    orientation: "vertical"
    id: action
ActionBar:
    size_hint_y: 0.1
    background_color: 0, 0, 1000, 10
    background_normal: ""
    ActionView:
        ActionPrevious:
        ActionButton:
            id: near_users
            icon: 'icons/internet.png'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'near_users'
        ActionButton:
            id: matching_bar
            text: "Matching"
            on_press: root.manager.current= 'match'
        ActionButton:
            id: chat
            text: "chat"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'chats'
        ActionButton:
            id: profile
            text: "Profile"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'profile'
Manager:
    id: screen_manager

<ScreenLogIn>:
     orientation: "vertical"
     id: login_screen
     BoxLayout:

     TextInput:
         id: login
     TextInput:
         id: passw
         password: True # hide password
     Button:
         text: "Log In"
         on_release: root.verify_credentials()

<ScreenNearUsers>:
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            id: grid
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            cols: 2
            row_default_height: '20dp'
            row_force_default: True
            spacing: 0, 0
            padding: 0, 0

<ScreenMatch>:
    Button:
        text:

<ScreenChats>:
    Button:
        text: "stuff3"

<ScreenUserProfile>:
    Button:
        text: "stuff4"

<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager
    screen_log_in: screen_log_in
    screen_near_users: screen_near_users
    screen_match: screen_match
    screen_chats: screen_chats
    screen_user_profile: screen_user_profile

ScreenLogIn:
    id: screen_log_in
    name: 'login'
    manager: screen_manager
ScreenNearUsers:
    id: screen_near_users
    name: 'near_users'
    manager: screen_manager
ScreenMatch:
    id: screen_match
    name: 'match'
    manager: screen_manager
ScreenChats:
    id: screen_chats
    name: 'chats'
    manager: screen_manager
ScreenUserProfile:
    id: screen_user_profile
    name: 'profile'
    manger: screen_manager
```

Comment: I cannot get the code you have provided to run. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It does run, the person below gave an answer so they got the code to run, no idea why you could not.

Comment: Compare your post to their answer. They reformatted your code to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Use a `BooleanProperty` and `ActionButton`'s `disabled` attribute (gray out ActionButtons) to prevent users from accessing the other screens.

### Python Code

1. Add BooleanProperty to import statement, `from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, BooleanProperty`
2. Add BooleanProperty, `access_denied = BooleanProperty(True)` in `class Menu()`
3. In `verify_credentials()` method, if password matched, set `access_denied` to `False`, else set it to `True`.

#### Snippet

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, BooleanProperty
...
class Menu(BoxLayout):
    access_denied = BooleanProperty(True)


class ScreenLogIn(Screen):

    def verify_credentials(self):
        try:
            if self.ids.login.text == "email@email.com" and self.ids.passw.text == "password":
                App.get_running_app().root.access_denied = False
                self.manager.current = "match"
            else:
                App.get_running_app().root.access_denied = True
                popup = Popup(title='Try again',
                              content=Label(text='Wrong Email/Password'),
                              size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400),
                              auto_dismiss=True)
                popup.open()
        except Exception as e:
            pass
```

### kv file

1. Check BooleanProperty, `access_denied` in each ActionButton

#### Snippet

```
        ActionButton:
            id: near_users
            icon: 'icons/internet.png'
            disabled: True if root.access_denied else False
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'near_users'

        ActionButton:
            id: matching_bar
            text: "Matching"
            disabled: True if root.access_denied else False
            on_press: root.manager.current= 'match'

        ActionButton:
            id: chat
            text: "chat"
            disabled: True if root.access_denied else False
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'chats'

        ActionButton:
            id: profile
            text: "Profile"
            disabled: True if root.access_denied else False
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'profile'
```

[Screen's default property manager](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#basic-usage)

> Each screen has by default a property manager that gives you the
>   instance of the ScreenManager used.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button


Builder.load_file('main.kv')


class Menu(BoxLayout):
    access_denied = BooleanProperty(True)


class ScreenLogIn(Screen):

    def verify_credentials(self):
        try:
            if self.ids.login.text == "email@email.com" and self.ids.passw.text == "password":
                App.get_running_app().root.access_denied = False
                self.manager.current = "match"
            else:
                App.get_running_app().root.access_denied = True
                popup = Popup(title='Try again',
                              content=Label(text='Wrong Email/Password'),
                              size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400),
                              auto_dismiss=True)
                popup.open()
        except Exception as e:
            pass


class ScreenNearUsers(Screen):

    def on_enter(self):
        for i in range(101):
            button = Button(text="B_" + str(i))
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(button)


class ScreenMatch(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenChats(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenUserProfile(Screen):
    pass


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    screen_log_in = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_near_user = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_match = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_chats = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_user_profile = ObjectProperty(None)


class MenuApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Menu()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MenuApp().run()
```

### main.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<Menu>:
    manager: screen_manager
    orientation: "vertical"
    id: action

    ActionBar:
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        background_color: 0, 0, 1000, 10
        background_normal: ""

        ActionView:
            ActionPrevious:

            ActionButton:
                id: near_users
                icon: 'icons/internet.png'
                disabled: True if root.access_denied else False
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'near_users'

            ActionButton:
                id: matching_bar
                text: "Matching"
                disabled: True if root.access_denied else False
                on_press: root.manager.current= 'match'

            ActionButton:
                id: chat
                text: "chat"
                disabled: True if root.access_denied else False
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'chats'

            ActionButton:
                id: profile
                text: "Profile"
                disabled: True if root.access_denied else False
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'profile'

    Manager:
        id: screen_manager

<ScreenLogIn>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    id: login_screen
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: login
        TextInput:
            id: passw
            password: True # hide password
        Button:
            text: "Log In"
            on_release: root.verify_credentials()

<ScreenNearUsers>:
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            id: grid
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            cols: 2
            row_default_height: '20dp'
            row_force_default: True
            spacing: 0, 0
            padding: 0, 0

<ScreenMatch>:
    Button:
        text:

<ScreenChats>:
    Button:
        text: "stuff3"

<ScreenUserProfile>:
    Button:
        text: "stuff4"

<Manager>:
    screen_log_in: screen_log_in
    screen_near_users: screen_near_users
    screen_match: screen_match
    screen_chats: screen_chats
    screen_user_profile: screen_user_profile

    ScreenLogIn:
        id: screen_log_in
        name: 'login'

    ScreenNearUsers:
        id: screen_near_users
        name: 'near_users'

    ScreenMatch:
        id: screen_match
        name: 'match'

    ScreenChats:
        id: screen_chats
        name: 'chats'

    ScreenUserProfile:
        id: screen_user_profile
        name: 'profile'
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - ActionButton grayed out]
[image: Img02 - clicked ActionButton near_users]

Comment: There is one issue some times if I click the button many times it allows me to bypass the login and go to that screen but, only for one button and its random what one it allows me to bypass the login screen. Why is this and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @jack041: I tried clicking many times on any ActionButtons and I was not able to bypass login with my example. Could you please provide sequence of steps in order for me to recreate the problem? Please update your post with the latest codes. Thank you.

Comment: All I do is click one of the buttons over and over again and it eventually lets me go to that screen.

Comment: Click one button many times if it does not do it go to the next, some times it even lets me go to more then just one of the screens.

Comment: For now I'm using an if statement, so even if there able to get to a screen with out first logging in. It just puts them back to the login if  access_denied is true but, I would really like to get to the bottom of this issue even tho I figured out a work around.

Comment: Running the example that I provided , I am not able to recreate that problem even after clicking more than 20 times on each ActionButton in sequence or randomly.